# How to reset MBR partition table macbook pro?

Tags: macos, bootloader, mbr

I used refind/refit's bootsync utility to update my macbook pro's mbr partition tables as a part of a triple booting process. Now I want to replace the operating system installed on one of the partitions with another one, and I figure I would have to go reset the mbr partition tables, format the drive in question and carry on the installation, before syncing the mbr partition table again with the same utility. How do I unsync the mbr partition table? Is there any other way of doing this? I don't want to format and repartition my hard drive.

Te three os's in question are Win 7, Debian and MAC OS X 10.9.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot from a linux cd/usb-stick and then use the typical partitioning tools such as fdisk/parted.

Then install the wished OS on the freed partition. You might have to re-setup your refit aferwards.

Good luck and **do a backup first!**